# laravelでwebアプリケーションを制作しています。エラーが出てどこを修正すればいいかわかりません

Tags: laravel

https://gyazo.com/444cce9c9f21cd8fd7e6be288f3e0cfd

localhost:8000でログインの後にこのような画面になります。laravelの.envで

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=todolist
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

としました。現在どうゆう状態で何をすればいいかわかりません。
.envじゃないfileを編集するのでしょうか？

https://gyazo.com/a2af5e845cdccb0b952c10112174cf47

エラーが出ると
/Users/yokoyamanaonori/todolist/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php
の664行目を見ろといわれてるとおもうのですが制作途中にこのConnection.phpにふれていないのですが
一体どうゆうことなのでしょうか？ご教授お願いいたします。

Comment: 現状どういう状態で何をすればよいかわからない、とのことですが、出ているエラーメッセージ SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found の意味はわかりますか？そこは理解された上でのご質問なのか、そこがわからない（あるいはエラーが出たらどう対処していったらいいのかがわからない）というご質問なのか、どのような感じでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

データベースtodolistにusersテーブルがないことが原因かと思われます。

Answer (score 0):

御返答頂き有難う御座います。
ルーティングとコントローラーチャンと理解
しないと駄目だと思い、一度プロジェクトの
ディレクトリそのものを削除してしまいました。
画面右上のログインとレジスタ？の後に
HTMLで制作したTOP画面にしたかったのです。
もう一度やってみようと思います。
todolistにusersてーぶるなないから、
venderのページ見なさいとなるのですね？